# Button click counter in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-button

I want to create an android voting app in which the number of times a button is clicked gets stored in the Firebase database.

So when the user clicks the button, the vote gets stored in Firebase. However I cannot figure out how to keep a count of how many times the button is pressed. Please help me out. 
Thanks

Comment: To keep count you could use a private member variable that is accessible in the whole class where your button is clicked. To temporarly deactivate it you could deactivate it,  start a timer which counts to 5s and then throws an event that reactivates it.

Comment: A. Hue thanks for the response. Can you please explain how to do in detail. Thanks

Comment: You can see how to use the timer in Milind Mevada's answer. As for the variable, just initialize an int variable (for example `int counter = 0;`) just below the start of your class not inside any function, so you can access it in every function of this class.

Comment: Member or class variables are a basic concept in many programming languages. You should take a look at it.

Comment: But you only want to keep count of the clicks during runtime, don't you? If not you could just check how many entries there are in firebase. I never worked with it so I don't know the commands. If it is only during runtime initialize the variable like I said above and add `counter++;` to Milind Mevada's `public void onClick(View v)`. You can then check the counter wherever you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update `firebase` data on `button` click event, and when ever Button is clicked make it `disable`.
You can further make it Enable using `handler` or `TimerTask` 
Here is Sample Example:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //update firebase
                btn.setEnabled(false);
            }
        });

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                btn.setEnabled(true);
            }
        },5*60*1000);
```